# How does a forward search attack work?

Tags: encryption, public-key, cryptanalysis, keys, symmetric

I just came across this term “forward search attack” while reading about Interchange key and Session key. The book mentioned that using session key helps to prevent attacks such as forward search attack.

Comment: Could you provide the name of the book and the page? Maybe the term is forward secrecy.

Comment: @kelalaka We have a potential dupe on our site: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15040/36960

Comment: @DannyNiu Quite possible, since the OP tagged public-key, that is a possible duplicate. Thanks to secure padding, this is history.